# Set default value or ignore Append Query Field that does not exist in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, append, suppress-warnings

I have a series of Excel Tools that work with an Access database (which is really the front end to a series of SharePoint lists). Each Excel Tool has an export function that creates a separate file (CSV) containing data to bring into the database. In the database, the CSV comes in as a local table, and an append query is run to add the contents of the local table to the SharePoint list. I am not fond of the architecture, but due to the robustness of my company's IT Security protocols, this is what I have to do.

There is a list of columns that COULD exist in the CSV, but whether they exist or not depends on the data entered into the workbook. For example, here are all the possible column headings:

- kWh Savings
- kw Savings
- Natural Gas Savings
- Water Savings
- Fuel Oil Savings
- Propane Savings

Depending on the customer/building/end use, some of the fields might not exist. For example, if this is a lighting calculator, no water savings will exist, and therefore that columns will not exist. Since the field does not exist, the append query throws a dialog box to ask me the parameter value. What I'm trying to accomplish is for it not to do this. I don't have a preference whether it just ignores the field, or if it defaults to 0. Any thoughts? Here are my queries that make the whole thing work:

```
[AppendFilter]
SELECT csv.*
FROM csv LEFT JOIN sharepoint ON (csv.FIM_Unique = sharepoint.FIM_Unique) AND (csv.[Building ID] = sharepoint.Building)
WHERE (((sharepoint.FIM_Unique) Is Null) AND ((sharepoint.Building) Is Null) AND ((csv.FIM_Unique) Is Not Null));
```

```
[AppendData]
INSERT INTO sharepoint ( FIM_Unique, FIM_Designation, [FIM Description], Safety_Factor, Building, [kWh Savings], [kW Savings], [Natural Gas Savings], [Water Savings], [Fuel Oil Savings], [Propane Savings] )
SELECT [AppendFilter].FIM_Unique, csv.[FIM Designation], csv.[FIM Description], csv.[Safety Factor], [AppendFilter].[Building ID], [AppendFilter].[kWh Savings], [AppendFilter].[kW Savings], [AppendFilter].[Natural Gas Savings], [AppendFilter].[Water Savings], [AppendFilter].[Fuel Oil Savings], [AppendFilter].[Propane Savings]
FROM [AppendFilter]. INNER JOIN csv ON [AppendFilter].FIM_Unique = csv.FIM_Unique
WHERE ((([AppendFilter].FIM_Unique) Is Not Null) AND (([AppendFilter].[Building ID]) Is Not Null));
```

I have tried `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` when running the query, but these warnings appear immune to that!

Comment: Are these query objects you are running? Use VBA to dynamically build SQL statements.

Comment: And those popups are not warnings, they are Access asking for missing info.

Comment: What would it look like to build a dynamic SQL statement to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could use VBA to dynamically build and execute SQL action. One way is with DAO TableDefs to iterate through table fields and build a string of field names and use string variable to build SQL statement. I don't think need to join CSV with AppendFilter. For one thing, doing so results in a SELECT query with duplicate field names and that will cause confusion unless fields are prefixed with table name.

However, gets complicated if field names are not same in source and destination tables. I see some variation with underscores and `Building ID` as opposed to `Building`. Since there are only 3 fields with variation, build string variable with conditional code to check for particular field names and make adjustment as appropriate.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, td As DAO.TableDef, fd As DAO.Field, strD As String, strF As String
Set db = CurrentDb
Set td = db.TableDefs("csv")
For Each fd In td.Fields
    strF = fd.Name
    If strF = "FIM Designation" Or strF = "Safety Factor" Then strF = Replace(strF, " ", "_")
    If strF = "Building ID" Then strF = "Building"
    strD = strD & "[" & strF & "],"
Next
strD = Left(strD, Len(strD) - 1)

db.Execute "INSERT INTO sharepoint(" & strD & ") " & _
"SELECT * FROM csv " & _
"WHERE FIM_Unique IN(SELECT FIM_Unique FROM AppendFilter)"
```

I strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Underscore is only exception but I never use that either.